# BigPipe seria aplicável nesse caso?

Tags: aplicação-web, facebook, desempenho

Estava a ler sobre como funciona grandes web-sites e cheguei a conhecer o BigPipe.

---

**O que é BigPipe (miúdos)**

O Bigpipe foi um recurso criado pelo facebook, o que ele faz é tornar o tempo de carregamento da página mais rápido, o conteúdo da página é dividido em partes chamadas "Pagelets" e pode carregar alguns deles simultaneamente ou item-a-item.

---

Pois bem, eu estou a trabalhar em um projeto um pouco grande e pensei em colocar essa técnica em prática, porém entrei em dúvida.

Minhas páginas são tecnicamente carregadas apenas uma vez, ou seja, o css js principal são carregados na index. Nessa página existe um `view`, é nesse view que as páginas são carregadas dentro através da função `load()` do jQuery e assim funciona meu site, as páginas são puxadas e carregadas ali. Levando em conta que essas páginas não contém arquivos, apenas html comprimido.

Uso sistema de cache interno e também externo para arquivos que não se alteram com frequência como imagens etc..

Minha pergunta, seria aproveitável usar o BigPipe nesse caso, ou não faria diferença de desempenho?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30151/discussion-on-question-by-user3163662-bigpipe-seria-aplicavel-nesse-caso)

Comment: Não entendo porque a pergunta foi fechada. A não ser que esteja enganado, a resposta me parece óbvia. A [técnica BigPipe](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919) serve principalmente para diminuir o tempo total em que a página pode ser visualizada pelo usuário, fazendo melhor uso do carregamento paralelo e assíncrono de trechos da página e recursos como CSS e JS. Se o sistema carrega esse recursos apenas uma vez e parece não ser dividido em seções lógicas e independentes, o BigPipe traz pouco ou nenhum ganho.

Comment: Boa noite @utluiz A pergunta foi fechada pelo fato (meu ponto de vista) de que *"usar ou não"* é algo que tem variação de servidor pra servidor e quantidade de clientes e qual o potencial que o projeto pretende atingir, sendo assim acredito que o autor entenda a técnica, mas não tem como responder se faria diferença no projeto dele, pois a pergunta foi esta *"ou não faria diferença de desempenho?"*, talvez tivéssemos que ter fechado como *não pode ser reproduzido*, mas ao meu ver não era bem por ae. No entanto podemos reabrir se achar interessante. Até amanhã.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo que a pergunta ficou bem específica para o projeto do AP. Porém eu vejo ela como "a técnica X pode ser usada no cenário Y?", o que seria perfeitamente respondível ainda que em teoria. Talvez se o AP mexer um pouco na pergunta, principalmente ao final, a coisa fique mais clara.

Comment: @user3163662, sugiro que altere um pouco o último parágrafo da sua pergunta para algo como: *Seria aplicável usar o BigPipe nesse cenário? Ele poderia contribuir para alguma diferença no desempenho?*. Acredito que dessa forma a pergunta fica menos opinativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Possivelmente** o ganho será pequeno, se houver algum, pois o BigPipe não parece uma técnica adequada para o cenário proposto na pergunta.

## Desempenho é uma caixa de surpresas

**Não** é possível afirmar se o BigPipe afetará positivamente ou até negativamente o desempenho de uma aplicação sem efetivamente realizar a implementação e coletar dados do antes e do depois.

Além disso, qualquer otimização deveria ser feita dentro de um contexto relevante. Usuários apresentam diferentes hábitos e necessidades de uso de um sistema. O BigPipe ajuda a paralelizar a exibição de uma página composta, mas será que o maior problema do usuário não é uma das consultas que demora muito para retornar? Num caso desses, você pode investir todos os recursos em técnicas de otimização e o usuário ainda vai estar insatisfeito porque a informação que interessa para ele continua a demorar a aparecer.

Só comece a pensar em técnicas complexas de otimização se realmente o desempenho for um problema e um diagnóstico foi realizado de forma que se tenha confiança que a técnica adequada foi selecionada. Nunca aplique técnicas de otimização sem isso, pois o custo para implementá-las e mantê-las é alto e será dinheiro jogado no ralo.

## Porque não usar o BigPipe

Pela descrição do sistema, não existem vários seções no sistema que são apresentadas num mesmo momento.

Uma implementação paralela que só exibe uma única página por vez apenas irá gerar sobrecarga no sistema, isto é, processamento desnecessário.

## Alternativas

Para um sistema que carrega todos os recursos apenas uma vez, a preocupação está no primeiro acesso que o usuário faz à página inicial.

Bem, o primeiro passo é colocar tudo que for estático, como imagens, estilos e scripts, minificado num CDN para garantir o menor tempo possível do download dos recursos.

Feito isso, meça o tempo de carregamento sem uso de cache. Se não for satisfatório, pode-se usar algumas técnicas simples:

### *Flush header early*

Alguns *engines* de templates montam a página toda e depois enviam para o usuário. Outros fazem *buferização*. O problema é que nesse caso o navegador vai ter que esperar o processamento no servidor até receber o cabeçalho e poder começar a baixar os estilos e scripts declarados.

Mude isso para que ocorra um *flush* que envie toda a tag `<head>` nos primeiros milissegundos da requisição. Dessa forma, enquanto o servidor pensa, o navegador está baixando os recursos.

Para que isso funciona ainda melhor, declare todas as tags `<script>` no cabeçalho com o atributo `async` para o o navegador não bloqueio o restante da página enquanto carrega os scripts.

### Pré-carregamento em segundo plano

Uma forma simples de dar uma sensação de fluidez é pré-carregar os recursos das telas em que o usuário vai acessar enquanto ele está fazendo alguma coisa.

Um exemplo bem simples seria pré-carregar os recursos estáticos do sistema de forma assíncrona enquanto o usuário está fazendo o login ou está olhando a página inicial.

É quase uma trapaça, mas dessa forma quando o usuário acessar uma tela do sistema o navegador vai ter os recursos em cache.

## Cuidado com cache

Sistemas que precisam escalar devem tentar ao máximo armazenar estado. Criar serviços *stateless* permitem distribuir o sistema, evitam delays com *code cache* (cache não inicializado), evitam *stale data* (dados antigos sendo usados de forma incorreta), e por aí vai.

Caches feitos indevidamente são uma dor de cabeça tremenda mais tarde, uma verdadeira fonte de problemas, limitações e bugs.

Cache distribuído é custoso para um sistema pequeno, afinal sincronizar informações também custa tempo, e é complicado para um sistema grande.

Um cache é como colocar um estado mutante no sistema e você vai sempre ter que se preocupar se esse estado está devidamente atualizado e como a atualização será feita. Muitas vezes não vale a pena.

## Desempenho depende da implementação

Independente da técnica de otimização que se aplica, sua implementação sempre vai falar alto.

Um BigPipe mal implementado pode aumentar o tempo total até o evento *ready for user*. Um cache mal implementado pode ser pior do que uma consulta ao banco de dados. Um código SQL que faz *table scan* pode ser pior uma chamada REST para um serviço externo.

Esses exemplos são razões para que a preocupação maior seja sempre com uma boa implementação do sistema e menos com técnicas específicas de melhoria de desempenho.

Comment: Ótima resposta, principalmente pelo *"isto é, processamento desnecessário."* +1

Comment: Eu havia me esquivado de alterar a pergunta por ter encontrado algo fruto de pesquisas que respondia minhas perguntas, mas você ainda me acrescentou mais coisas, obrigada! Por fim eu irei alterar algumas estruturas do meu projeto afim de implementar algumas coisas simples e tornar tudo harmônico.

Comment: Acho legal ressaltar que testes de desempenho devem ser realizados. Eu fiz, um breve, com BigPipe  a página carregou o DOM em 385ms e a página em sí em 1.30s . Sem ele o DOM carregou em 754ms e a página em si em 915ms. É perceptível a diferença.. Mas fica a pergunta no ar, é realmente necessário ?

Comment: Tem outros números agradáveis, que me mostram pelo menos superficialmente que o BigPipe traz algumas melhorias que em grande escala seria significativo, mas traz pontos negativos. No meu caso claro..

Comment: @user3163662 Pontos interessantes. Só note que não é preciso usar necessariamente o BigPipe para fazer a página carregar antes. BigPipe é um caso específico que envolve uma composição de pequenas técnicas para exibição simultânea de múltiplas partes em uma página. O importante é sempre dar a resposta visual para o usuário mais cedo possível e, dependendo do caso, isso pode ser feito de forma simples. Por exemplo, remova scripts desnecessários e faça os necessários executarem depois da página ser exibida. Faça batch dos resources estáticos e o flush imediato do header.

Comment: @user3163662 Desculpe chover no molhado, mas fica apenas para enfatizar. Você parece saber o que está fazendo.